# How to solve ORA-12154: TNS error when using PHP OCI8 oci_connect in Azure

Tags: php, oracle, azure, oci8

I'm trying to connect to the oracle database of a new partner, 11g Release 11.2.0.4.0, and I'm receiving the following error:

> **Warning:** oci_connect(): ORA-12545: Connect failed because target host or object does not exist

The partner affirms that the connection string provided is correct.

This is the current structure of mine oci_connect() and the said connection string being used:

```
$connection_string = '(DESCRIPTION = (ADDRESS_LIST = (LOAD_BALANCE = ON)(FAILOVER = ON)(ADDRESS = (PROTOCOL = TCP)(HOST = HOST)(PORT = 1521)))(CONNECT_DATA = (SERVICE_NAME = SERVICE_NAME)))'
$conn = oci_connect($username, $password, $connection_string, 'UTF8', OCI_DEFAULT);
```

But, when using the following structure:

```
$connection_string = 'user/password@host:port/service_name'
$conn = oci_connect($username, $password, $connection_string, 'UTF8', OCI_DEFAULT);
```

It returns:

> **Warning**: oci_connect(): ORA-12154: TNS:could not resolve the connect identifier specified

To give a clear picture of what I did, below are the steps I took to create my App-Service and install the oci8 php driver:

1. I created an Azure App-Service, that uses PHP, Version 7.3.26;
2. Created a new oracle directory inside /home/site;
3. Added the instant client to the new oracle directory, in this case it was the Instant Client Linux x86-64 18.5.0.0.0v (bouth the basic and the sdk packages);
4. Proceded to use the command pecl install oci8-2.2.0;
5. I pointed out the location of the instant client during the installation process, the oci8 driver was installed successfully;
6. Copied the new oci8.so file to an ext directory inside /home/site;
7. Created a php.ini file, with extension=/home/site/ext/oci8.so set in;
8. Defined the PHP_INI_SCAN_DIR config as being /usr/local/etc/php/conf.d:/home/site/ini;
9. Defined the LD_LIBRARY_PATH as being /home/site/oracle/instantclient_18_5.

After that I could confirm the existence of the oci8 extension on my phpinfo() page.

Those steps where made following this documentation: [Azure App Service Linux - Adding PHP Extensions](https://azureossd.github.io/2019/01/29/azure-app-service-linux-adding-php-extensions/)

I also have latter defined the ORACLE_HOME setting as being /home/site/oracle/instantclient_18_5, but it had no diferences.

I'm out of ideas, can someone please indicate me what could be causing this problem and how can I solve it.

---

**EDIT:**

After further conversations with the partner it becamed clear that there isn't no way for me to connect to their database considering the current configuration of the same. As noted int the comments by Christopher Jones, its a problem of networking, [ORA-12545, ORA-12541, ORA-12514, & ORA-01017 – How to fix for SQL Developer](https://www.thatjeffsmith.com/archive/2014/09/ora-12545-12541-12514-01017/), and, in this case, lack of proper feedback.

Comment: username and password are in separate arguments to `oci_connect()`, they shouldn't be in the connection string as well.

Comment: Sory @Barmar I tried to change the connection string to host:port/service_name in the second example, it didn't worked to.

Comment: What does your actual connect string look like? These should all be private IPs or names, there's no security risk here.

Comment: See also the troubleshooting section of the [install documentation](https://www.php.net/manual/en/oci8.installation.php): "While network errors like ORA-12154 or ORA-12514 indicate an Oracle network naming or configuration issue, the root cause may be because the PHP environment is incorrectly set up and Oracle libraries are unable to locate the tnsnames.ora configuration file."

Comment: Hey @miken32, sorry if it's a newbie question, shouldn't I be able to connect without a tnsnames.ora file if using a easy connect naming method?

Comment: Honestly I have no idea, but it looks like there are other environment variables and such that need to be set. Did you go through that page and ensure all were set appropriately?

Comment: After reading your comment, I did check the environment variables, and it didn't had a TNS_ADMIN setup, neither any tnsnames.ora file, I tried creating a tnsnames.ora with the provided credentials, but I don't know if this is the correct aproach, and it didn't work to, the same as the second warning. Before continuing this proccess I must ask you one more question, do you know if it is viable or not to use PHP oci8 for connecting an on premise oracle database?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/233153/discussion-between-joao-zucchinali-and-miken32).

Comment: I have never used an Oracle database of any sort in my life, nor connected to one in PHP code.

Comment: Ok, nevertheless thanks for the help

Comment: For the host:post/service and `'(DESCRIPTION...` syntaxes you do not need to create a tnsnames.ora file or set TNS_ADMIN.  Don't set ORACLE_HOME with Instant Client. Your problem is networking between computers. Read https://www.thatjeffsmith.com/archive/2014/09/ora-12545-12541-12514-01017/   Can you  you update your question with what you've tried? E.g. remove the username & password from the 2nd example connection string host:port/service_name as suggested.  And clarify the full string `'(DESCRIPTION =...` usages - I presume you actually have a real hostname for the second HOST in it?

Comment: @ChristopherJones, I do have a real hostname and still get the same error after removing the username & password from the 2nd example as suggested. This errors where expected though, after new conversations with this new partner it becamed clear that their database wasn't able to make connections. Unfortunately I might need to find a new workaround for this case, having in mind the barriers they have for providing a connection. I will update my question as suggested, thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Ok,

So I fought with this for a long time and could *never* get it to find the tnsnames.ora file no matter what I did.  Finally I decided to pull the connection string definition out of the tnsnames.ora file and insert it directly into the oci_connect statement as the connection string and it worked:

```
//$connection_string = '(DESCRIPTION = (ADDRESS_LIST = (LOAD_BALANCE = ON)(FAILOVER = ON)(ADDRESS = (PROTOCOL = TCP)(HOST = HOST)(PORT = 1521)))(CONNECT_DATA = (SERVICE_NAME = SERVICE_NAME)))'
$connection_string = '(DESCRIPTION=(ADDRESS=(PROTOCOL=TCP)(HOST=192.168.0.10)(PORT=1521))(CONNECT_DATA=(SERVER = DEDICATED)(SERVICE_NAME = pdb_mypdb.xyz.com)))';
$conn = oci_connect("mypdb", "mypdbpw", $connection_string );
```

What is even more cool is that in a lot of third-party programs, when they ask for the name of the oracle server, you can put the ENTIRE  tnsnames.ora CONNECT definition (like above, in $connection_string) in to the "server name" and it will work.  You don't even need tnsnames.ora, etc. and all the load-balancing, etc., will all work.

Good luck,
David

Comment: and this works everywhere, not just on azure.

Comment: You can also use Oracle's "Easy Connect" syntax, introduced in Oracle 10, and extended in recent versions, notable in 19c with additional URL-style options. See the technical brief https://download.oracle.com/ocomdocs/global/Oracle-Net-21c-Easy-Connect-Plus.pdf

Comment: @ChristopherJones, I really appreciate that.  I used the above nomenclature because Easy Connect and Easy Connect+ do not seem to work on my installation and Oracle could not figure out why, nor could our consultant.  I am glad you mentioned it because someone should try it before my solution.